# How can i launch a test in firefox with device emulation using Testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I could run the test with firefox like in the example below:

`testcafe "firefox" tests/sample-fixture.js`

How could i launch the tests to show in firefox with device emulation?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only run Chrome with device emulation. In Firefox, you can only resize the window. Also, you may [create your suggestion to improve TestCafe on GitHub](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A%20enhancement&template=feature_request.yaml).